# How to extract data from json object sent from android

Tags: javascript, json

```
var barData = {
                labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
                datasets: [
                    {
                        label: "My First dataset",
                        fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
                        strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                        pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
                        pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                        data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
                    }
                ]
            };
```

This is the json object encoded with all the data sent from an android application to javascript. Now in javascript, how can i access the labels array or datasets array from barData json object?

I want to get **labels[0]** which is **January** alongwith **datasets[0].data[0]** which is **65**. This is the code which I've been trying but failed. Can you please provide me with a solution, an easy one?
Thanks anyways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access it by `barData.labels[index]` index 0,1,2 etc

Answer (score 0):

You can retrive your object from json using [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Comment: Mark as correct pls, that's helpful for me and other users